# My PHP Implode function does not work

Tags: php

I'm trying to make this implode function work.

This is the form part, assume all the item has been selected.

```
<form method="post">
<select name="test1" multiple="multiple" id="test1">
   <option value="1">item1</option>
   <option value="2">item2</option>
   <option value="3">item3</option>
   <option value="4">item4</option>
   <option value="5">item5</option>
</select>
</form>
```

The PHP part

```
<?php
$var1 = array();
$joinedString = array();
$var1 = $_POST['test1'];
$joinedString = implode(',', $var1);
?>
```

But The echoing part doesn't work, it gives me error, and only displaying only the first array value.

```
<?php
$echo $joinedString[0];
$echo $joinedString[1];
$echo $joinedString[2];
$echo $joinedString[3];
$echo $joinedString[4];
?>
```

Thank You guys, I'm quite new in programming. I always forgot that the code executed line by line, and always confused with variable and values, and yes, in real world I am also a clumsy & insignificant person.

Comment: what are you trying to do? JOIN an array, or SPLIT a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="sear.php">
 <select name="test1[]" multiple="multiple" id="test1">
   <option value="1">item1</option>
   <option value="2">item2</option>
   <option value="3">item3</option>
   <option value="4">item4</option>
   <option value="5">item5</option>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </select>
</form>
<?php
   $var1 = array();
   $joinedString = array();
   $var1 = $_POST['test1'];
   $joinedString = implode(',', $var1);
   echo $joinedString;
?>
```

After getting the post values it definitely works.... Try it...

Comment: yes, It's working now, how insignificant I am. thank you sir. next stop, sql left join() function.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<select name="test1" multiple="multiple" id="test1">
```

to

```
<select name="test1[]" multiple="multiple" id="test1">
```

And it's already an array

```
$var1 = $_POST['test1'];
    $imploded = implode(",", $var1);
    echo $imploded;
    //FOR GETTING INDIVIDUAL ITEMS FROM array
    echo $var1[0];
```

Comment: so i just can call it like this : $val=$_post['test1[0]'];?

Comment: Thank You Madame, now I just need to add the foreach loop to identify array values.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<select name="test1[]" multiple="multiple" id="test1">
```

In php file.

```
$var1 = isset($_POST['test1']) ? $_POST['test1']: 0 ;
print_r($var1); //gives array
foreach($var1 as $var) {
    echo $var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implode is not getting any array. Its works on Array.

Comment: so, what function on getting array of values?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string instead of an array. `implode()` turns an array into a string.

Answer (score 0):

In your script, $_POST['test1'] will only contain the submitted value of the select box, not the entire set of values.  Since $var1 contains only a string, implode() will error out.

Answer (score 0):

Just look up this:

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-string-implode.php

And `$` is used with variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** your array using (,) but post array values does not contain values seperated by comma, therefore you will have to use **[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**.

```
<?php
$var1 = array();
$joinedString = array();
$var1 = $_POST['test1'];
foreach($var1 as $values)
echo $values."<br/>";
?>

<form method="post">
<select name="test1[]" multiple="multiple" id="test1">
   <option value="1">item1</option>
   <option value="2">item2</option>
   <option value="3">item3</option>
   <option value="4">item4</option>
   <option value="5">item5</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: OMG, very straightforward.. Thank You Sibu.

Comment: @ThePowerintheRightHand i guess for getting selected values you don't have to follow such long procedure as others have mentioned :-)

Comment: I hope not, lol. my brain having a meltdown right now.. probably need to rest for awhile to avoid making simple mistakes.

Comment: @ThePowerintheRightHand just rest, it will come with practice